# Rails 5 fields_for nesting under a collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-helpers

So I have a model with this structure:

```
document { 
  structure { 
    id, 
    ... 
  }, 
  fields { 
    field { 
      id,
      ...
    }, 
    value { 
      ... 
    } 
  } 
}
```

And I'm trying to put together a form for the fields, where the fields would look like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="document[fields][0][field][id]" />
<input type="text" name="document[fields][0][value]" />

<input type="hidden" name="document[fields][1][field][id]" />
<input type="text" name="document[fields][1][value]" />

...
```

This is what I'm currently doing:

```
  <%= document.fields.each_with_index do |df, i| %>
    <%= f.fields_for "fields[]", df do |builder| %>
      <p>
        <%= builder.label df.field.name %>
        <%= builder.fields_for :field do |field_builder| %>
          <%= field_builder.hidden_field :id, value: df.field.id %>
        <% end %>

        <%= builder.fields_for :value do |value_builder| %>
          <%= render df.field.edit_view, field: df.field, builder: value_builder %>
        <% end %>
      </p>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

But the resulting field names are:

```
document[fields][field][id]
document[fields][value][value]
```

In other words, the indices are missing.

Using `<%= builder.hidden_field :id, value: df.field.id %>` results in the correct format but no index (because the field object has no id yet): `document[fields][][id]` but that is not an option for value, as there could be multiple fields involved.

Is there a way to do this using the form helpers, or is what I'm doing just too wonky?

Edit: Here are the models involved:

The idea is to have a configurable set of fields for document. The structure determines fields available, and a document_field is a relation between a document and a field with a value contained.

```
class Field < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :structure
end

class Document < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :structure
    has_many :document_fields

class DocumentField < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :document
  belongs_to :field

class Structure < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :fields
```

Comment: Could you add your models, to try to reproduce your scenario?

Comment: Added to the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should configure a [nested attributes setup on your models](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html), build those nested relations on the controller, and instantiate an object in you `form_for` block instead of passing a referencing symbol.

Comment: That works for document_field[field], but not for value, which is not a separate model, it's just a JSON object containing arbitrarily structured data... How do I use something like accepts_nested_attributes_for for something like that?